SharePoint Approval Link not Showing
Can someone help me with my problem? I created a power automate approval in SharePoint. The requestor will fill the request form then it will automatically send email to approver. But the approver can't see the details when clicking the link.






Both of your images exposes your domain and tenant URL. You should mask those.

Can you show the approval action configuration in flow? What expression/dynamic content you used for link in approval action?

Here is the flow i use sir hoping it will help you know the problem

Power Automate action "Start approval" does not grant permissions.
You should take one of two paths:

Extract item metadata and format in user-friendly format, place in approval message (so users do not need to go to item for more info);
Grant all approvers at least read permissions to the item - do it before starting approval (flow will be waiting on approval action so permissions must be granted before).

